# Heatmap of large 2D array using datashader and plotly

Tags: python, aggregation, heatmap, plotly

I’m trying to show a **heatmap of a large 2D array** (160x250000 entries). This should go into a dash app so I'm using **plotly** to deal with graphics and my idea was to use **datashader** for performance but I’m having troubles getting it right. However, independently of dash I’m already having problem with plotly + datashader (see code below). There is probably something very basic I’m not understanding in this process. It would be great if someone could tell me what I’m doing wrong.

Below you can find a minimal example to reproduce the issue (using offline.plot since I’m using spyder to run it).

If I’m not wrong, the code is defining a grid of 900x300 and the value represented in each element of the grid is the mean of the original 2D array entries falling in that grid element. Now, I’m expecting the figure to keep the resolution fixed as I zoom in and to show more fine-grained details - at some point, if I zoom in enough, in each grid element there should be just one entry of the original 2D array.

However **when I zoom in in the produced figure the aggregation does not change**.

I'm using plotly 4.12.0 and datashader 0.11.1. Please let me know if further information is needed.
Any help understanding this would be much appreciated.

````
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
import numpy as np
import datashader as ds
from datashader import reductions as rd
import xarray as xr

pw_s = np.random.randn(150, 25000)
pw_s[:, 10000:] += 3
pw_s = xr.DataArray(pw_s, coords=[('y', np.arange(150)),
                                  ('time', np.arange(25000)/2000)])
cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=900, plot_height=300,
                x_range=(0, 25000/2000),
                y_range=(0, 150))
agg = cvs.raster(pw_s, agg=rd.mean())

fig = px.imshow(agg)
plot(fig)
```
````

Comment: Here you shouldn't expect the figure to update, because you are computing and then plotting "agg", which is simply an xarray DataArray, i.e., a fixed 900x300 array of values. Try printing "agg" and "type(agg)" to see! If you want a dynamically updating plot, you'll need a callback that invokes datashader every time you zoom or pan in plotly. Plotly is working on making that easy with Dash using holoviews.org, and I think they will announce that support very soon (next couple of weeks?). I'll ask someone from Plotly to comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment @JamesA.Bednar indeed today, investigating more I saw that and suspected I had to write a callback but I don't know what I should do in the callback. It would be great if they make this easy with holoviews (indeed using bokeh and holoviews it works smoothly). Anyway if someone from Plotly could provide some hints in the meantime it would be much appreciated.